# Docker ELK 5.4.0 - Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more information

Tags: docker, docker-compose, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm experiencing troubles on kibana official docker ELK stack. 
I'm using docker compose to startup a complete stack made of elasticsearch, logstash and kibana. 
The stack seems fine to me and everything is ok in logstash and elasticsearch. i can find everithing as expected inside the relative logs (docker logs -f $container_id). 
But when I try to access kibana web console I get this error:

> Kibana did not load properly. Check the server output for more
>   information.

Not every request ends up with this error. **sometimes** the page loads with broken styles or missing images. I can't understand why. I found occurences of the same problem on the web, but no solutions suggested is working for me. Also, the problem is that at the moment i'm not even able to fully understand the problem. **It seems to me** something related to internal http routing between the containers but to be honest i'm not sure

I'm attaching every useful information.

Thank you!

docker ps output:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
00862576b0e9        docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.0                 "/bin/sh -c /usr/l..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp             beaconelk_kibana_1
f9263d8f6c93        docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.4.0             "/usr/local/bin/do..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       5044/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9600->9600/tcp   beaconelk_logstash_1
4cbd3b13d074        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0   "/bin/bash bin/es-..."   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       9200/tcp, 9300/tcp                 beaconelk_elasticsearch_1
```

Kibana logs (some strange 304):

```
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:kibana@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["error","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Request error, retrying\nHEAD http://elasticsearch:9200/ => connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:9200"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:28Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:29Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:29Z","tags":["status","plugin:monitoring@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:29Z","tags":["reporting","warning"],"pid":1,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.reporting.encryptionKey. To prevent pending reports from failing on restart, please set xpack.reporting.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:29Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:34Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:37Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:46Z","tags":["status","plugin:security@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:46Z","tags":["security","warning"],"pid":1,"message":"Generating a random key for xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in kibana.yml"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:46Z","tags":["security","warning"],"pid":1,"message":"Session cookies will be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:46Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:46Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - Waiting for Elasticsearch","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:tilemap@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:watcher@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to red - Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200.","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:console@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:metrics@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:security@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from yellow to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Elasticsearch"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:tilemap@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:watcher@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from red to yellow - No existing Kibana index found","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:timelion@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to green - Ready","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":1,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","ui settings","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from uninitialized to yellow - Elasticsearch plugin is yellow","prevState":"uninitialized","prevMsg":"uninitialized"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","error"],"pid":1,"state":"red","message":"Status changed from yellow to red - Service Unavailable","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Kibana index ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","ui settings","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Elasticsearch plugin is yellow"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["license","info","xpack"],"pid":1,"message":"Imported license information from Elasticsearch for [data] cluster: mode: trial | status: active | expiry date: 2017-06-21T10:24:40+00:00"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:xpack_main@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:graph@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:reporting@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:security@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:searchprofiler@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Service Unavailable"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:tilemap@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:watcher@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No existing Kibana index found"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["license","info","xpack"],"pid":1,"message":"Imported license information from Elasticsearch for [monitoring] cluster: mode: trial | status: active | expiry date: 2017-06-21T10:24:40+00:00"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:47Z","tags":["status","plugin:monitoring@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from green to yellow - Waiting for Monitoring Health Check","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:49Z","tags":["status","plugin:monitoring@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"Waiting for Monitoring Health Check"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:50Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from green to yellow - No .ml-anomalies-* index pattern found - creating index pattern","prevState":"green","prevMsg":"Ready"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:50Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"yellow","message":"Status changed from yellow to yellow - No .ml-notifications index pattern found - creating index pattern","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No .ml-anomalies-* index pattern found - creating index pattern"}
{"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:52Z","tags":["status","plugin:ml@5.4.0","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from yellow to green - Ready","prevState":"yellow","prevMsg":"No .ml-notifications index pattern found - creating index pattern"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/app/kibana","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","cache-control":"max-age=0","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":304,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /app/kibana 200 304ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_300.woff2","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","origin":"http://localhost:5601","if-none-match":"\"2da4d6d1b1bef32c05719680145b61613b3829b4\"","if-modified-since":"Fri, 28 Apr 2017 17:55:02 GMT","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"*/*","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":25,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/fonts/open_sans/open_sans_v13_latin_300.woff2 304 25ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/commons.style.css?v=15063","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/css,*/*;q=0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4","if-none-match":"\"beb4383d80d2e37de171d93229b3bbac7adf053d-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Tue, 09 May 2017 00:30:03 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":11,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/commons.style.css?v=15063 304 11ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/bundles/kibana.style.css?v=15063","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/css,*/*;q=0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4","if-none-match":"\"2c50da9e3b7cf991930ae6ef8b6539b6c0c6662c-gzip\"","if-modified-since":"Tue, 09 May 2017 00:30:03 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":22,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /bundles/kibana.style.css?v=15063 304 22ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/favicons/favicon-16x16.png","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4","if-none-match":"\"f33f077bfe13045136046c93b6180be0379386ff\"","if-modified-since":"Fri, 28 Apr 2017 17:55:02 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":9,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/favicons/favicon-16x16.png 304 9ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:53Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":304,"req":{"url":"/ui/favicons/favicon-32x32.png","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"image/webp,image/*,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4","if-none-match":"\"128bd421ef426ccdd9ea3293f79d25687b9832e7\"","if-modified-since":"Fri, 28 Apr 2017 17:55:02 GMT"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/app/kibana"},"res":{"statusCode":304,"responseTime":3,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /ui/favicons/favicon-32x32.png 304 3ms - 9.0B"}
{"type":"response","@timestamp":"2017-05-22T10:24:54Z","tags":[],"pid":1,"method":"get","statusCode":200,"req":{"url":"/app/kibana","method":"get","headers":{"host":"localhost:5601","connection":"keep-alive","cache-control":"max-age=0","upgrade-insecure-requests":"1","user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36","accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8","referer":"http://localhost:5601/","accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate, sdch, br","accept-language":"it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4"},"remoteAddress":"172.18.0.1","userAgent":"172.18.0.1","referer":"http://localhost:5601/"},"res":{"statusCode":200,"responseTime":21,"contentLength":9},"message":"GET /app/kibana 200 21ms - 9.0B"}
```

My browser output:[image]

this is my compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
    elasticsearch:
      image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.0
      restart: always
      environment:
        - http.host=0.0.0.0 
        - transport.host=0.0.0.0
        - xpack.security.enabled=false
    logstash:
      image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:5.4.0
      restart: always
      volumes:
        - "${LOGSTASH_PIPELINE_PATH}:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/"
      depends_on:
        - "elasticsearch"    
      ports:
        - ${LOGSTASH_EXPOSE_PORT}:9600
    kibana:
      image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.4.0
      restart: always
      depends_on:
        - "logstash"   
      ports:
        - ${KIBANA_EXPOSE_PORT}:5601
```

and my .env file in the same dir:

```
LOGSTASH_PIPELINE_PATH=/Users/andreadilisio/Documents/development/docker/beacon-elk/logstash-pipeline
KIBANA_EXPOSE_PORT=5601
LOGSTASH_EXPOSE_PORT=9600
```

and my logstash configuration:

```
input { 
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 9600
  }
}

filter {
  json{
      source => "message"
      skip_on_invalid_json => false
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { 
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"]
    user => elastic
    password => changeme
  }
}
```